# How to close the previous confirm box and open new one on accept or reject in PrimNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I am having to confirm the box on which one click of the accept button opens the new confirm box.

When I try to call on accept method it is not invoking new confirm box, Is there anyway I can get that?

Below is the stackblitz for reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-confirmdialog-demo-stzy7i

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open a confirmation dialog with the same reference. The old dialog is still open when `accept` callback is executed (due to the animation, I guess).

You need to create a different `p-confirmDialog` for each dialog to make them both fully independent (using `key` property).

[StackBlitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-confirmdialog-demo-jsfdk8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Template:

```
<p-confirmDialog key="confirm1" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000"></p-confirmDialog>
<p-confirmDialog key="confirm2" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000"></p-confirmDialog>
<p-button (click)="confirm1()" icon="pi pi-check" label="Confirm"></p-button>
<p-button (click)="confirm2()" icon="pi pi-times" label="Delete"></p-button>
```

Typescript:

```
confirm1() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      key: 'confirm1',
      message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.confirm2();
        // this.msgs = [{severity:'info', summary:'Confirmed', detail:'You have accepted'}];
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.msgs = [
          { severity: 'info', summary: 'Rejected', detail: 'You have rejected' }
        ];
      }
    });
  }

confirm2() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      key: 'confirm2',
      ...everythingElse
    });
  }
```